# Will there be any inconvenience if two objects of different classes add two same-named listeners to the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3

For expample like this:

```
package {
    class A {
        public A() {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, jump);
}}}
```

and

```
package {
    class B {
        public B() {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, jump);
}}}
```

I don't mean exact code, this one may not work, just to clear my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because each jump method will be local to the Class instance that added it.  Make sure that you include code to remove the event listener when the instance is destroyed, or you'll get a memory leak, since stage always exists.

Comment: and what about @ymutlu -s answer? o.O

Answer (score 2):

You need such methods for both class.

```
package {
class A {
  public function jump(){
    trace("this is jump on A");
  }
  public A() {
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, jump);
  }
}
package {
  class B {
    public function jump(){
      trace("this is jump on B");
    }
    public B() {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, jump);
    }
  }
}
```

Both jump method will be invodek when stage dispatches mouseUp event. if you use somthing like
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage.jump);. This ll me stage jump method called two times.

Hope it helps.